# Symfony: Add Column to Doctrine Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to learn the basics of Symfony, and have come across a problem that baffles me.

I'm trying to write Data to a SQL Table, following (mostly) the instructions from the documentation ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html ). I created an entity via

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

and it is mapped to my DB Table correctly, I can read and write, no problem. After that I added a column to my table and the corresponding lines to my Entity:

```
/**
 *  @var string
 *
 *  @ORM\Column(name="User_Credentials", type="text")
 */
private $userCredentials;
```

Then I tried creating the setters and getters, but no changes were made, just a backup of my Entity. So I added getter and setter myself, but when attempting to write to the DB the corresponding column is ommited, remaining empty. No errors are given. I checked and re-checked for typos or other sytax errors, but could not find any. When doing

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I get

```
ALTER TABLE st_users DROP User_Credentials;
```

So it seems my Column is completely ignored. I cleared the cache repatedly, which changed nothing. I am, obviously, lost. Any hint as to the right path will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) for this operations. This bundle will manage your database operations. (Drop, Alter, Create etc.)

Anyway, when you add a new column you can try this: `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: Well, that dropped my new column from the table. Anyway, I will look into migrations. I guess I need to install that bundle?

Comment: yes, i offer work with that bundle. You'll see it will save your life :)

Comment: I installed the bundle, added it to the kernel and run 'php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff'. It told me there were 'No changes detected in your mapping information'. schema:update did not change anything in the table - still the same problem, it wont detect my changes.

Comment: Did you add doctrine_migrations configs to your config.yml ?

Comment: Here is what I added there:
'# Doctrine Migrations
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: "%kernel.root_dir%/DoctrineMigrations"
    namespace: Application\Migrations
    table_name: migration_versions
    name: Application Migrations'

Comment: Can you try `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

Comment: Still 'No changes detected in your mapping information'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101785/discussion-between-mert-oksuz-and-124c41).

Comment: Notice: you need make changes after installation of DoctrineMigrationsBundle. You can save your before changes.

Comment: I changed the name of my new var as well as getter/setter - still no changes detected. Btw., I'm in the chat now.

Comment: CLEAR ALL CACHES before! I spend hours on this until I realized redis+doctrine cache are messing things up :/ Symfony is not smart!

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is embarassing...

Anyway, if someone else is having the same problem: I had a Tab before the '@ORM\Column' annotation, and it seems the parser can't handle that. Deleting the tab and adding a space did the trick.

Mert's answer is correct anyway, so I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I added a column to my table and the corresponding lines to my Entity

The concept of Symfony is to add column only to entity, but not to table itself.

Then, when you execute

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Symfony would detect that you have a new column and it will add column to the table **automatically**.

PS. Regarding clearing a cache. In case apc cache is enabled in Symfony - you also need to restart Apache or php-fpm process. Otherwise it will ignore new annotations.